# How to use UntypedActorFactory() in Akka 2.2.4

Tags: java, akka

I am migrating from akka 2.1 to akka 2.2.4 but im encountering some failures in message sending between actors due to `UntypedActorFactory()` deprecated method. Can anyone help me in converting this code:

```
public EventWorkerSuperVisor() 
{
ActorRef eventWorkerRouter = getContext().actorOf(new Props(
      new UntypedActorFactory() {
         public UntypedActor create() {
              return new EventWorker();
         }
      }).withRouter(new RandomRouter(10).withSupervisorStrategy(strategy)),
                      "Event-Worker-Router");



       to conform to the creator method...


static class MyActorC implements Creator<MyActor> {
     @Override public MyActor create() {
          return new MyActor("...");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't compiled but should be, using `Props.create()` :

```
ActorRef eventWorkerRouter = getContext().actorOf(
    Props.create(EventWorker.class).withRouter(...
```

Or if you need the `Creator<>` syntax,

```
ActorRef eventWorkerRouter = getContext().actorOf(
    Props.create(new MyActorC())).withRouter(...
```